# Laravel Undefined Call to undefined function iconv_strlen()

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

guys do you have some answer on this a strange bug ? I moved my project from another server and i configured all but i watching some bug Laravel give me a this error :

```
FatalErrorException in /public_html/app/Http/Controllers/GameController.php line 718:
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\iconv_strlen()
```

In this code:

```
 public function DepositRedirect()
{
    if(Auth::guest()) return 'You must be authorized!';
    if(!$this->user->trade) return 'You must set trade list in your profile!';
    $bot = DB::table('bots')->first();
    if(is_null($bot)) return "Bot not found!";
    if(iconv_strlen($bot->trade) < 1) return "Admin hasn't set trade link with bot.";
    return redirect($bot->trade);
}
```

Why ? This is standart php function for returns the character count of string i use php 7.X

Comment: Can you create a minimal but complete script, that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use

```
 if(empty($bot->trade) || iconv_strlen($bot->trade) < 1)
```

This will skip the second statement if the first is true

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem guys , problem is comming from my php i dont know why ,but i using zesleCP and in global php iconv is enable but in account php maybe is not and not working i just replace iconv_strlen() function with mb_strlen() and problem is solved but i will search method how to fixing iconv function :)

Answer (score 0):

you should simply add extension=iconv.so in your php.ini

/opt/zesle/zesle-php71/root/etc/php.ini

/opt/zesle/zesle-php56/root/etc/php.ini